# Page transitions in angular

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mobile, angularjs, css-transitions

I'm building a mobile app with angular and I'm trying to achieve page transitions when switching between views.

I know they released animations with 1.1.4, but does that work between views too? I'm not using the angular-routing however, which I think makes things more tricky. I'm building things in ASP.NET MVC and printing out the things we need with Razor.

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
       <head>
             //Normal head-stuff
       </head>

        <body>
           <div class="main">
               @RenderBody       <----The angular app goes here
           </div>
        </body>

   </html>
```

I tried implementing fasw transitions:
http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/non-jquery-page-transitions-lightweight/

But then I ended up sliding the whole page without rendering the new angular view, i.e, all white.

Is there a way to have a normal link and have the page transition between the angular views and how can I achieve it?

I'm thinking that I can maybe use ng-animate on the whole view when it has loaded, would that work?

Comment: It may not be exactly what you want, but there is a jquery mobile angular adapter:  https://github.com/tigbro/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter

Answer (score 1):

In this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cF_JsA9KsDM) around the 20:10 Miŝko Hevery said:

> ngAnimate has this concepts of DOM elements entering, moving around or leaving the stage and also elements been shown and hidden, so that's the vocabulary that ngAnimate understands...

also he mention ngView among the things that are affected with ngAnimate.

- [examples here](http://yearofmoo-articles.github.io/angularjs-animation-article/app/#/ng-repeat).
- [source code of examples here](https://github.com/mhevery/AngularJS-Animation-Article).

Hope this help.